# Continuous Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeerror

I'm new to JQuery and I have been working this code a long time and cannot get it to work. When I open is up in the console their's a continuous string of error messages that's impacting performance.

**Updated**: The errors start when you scroll pass 400px.

[Link](http://terrancesandbox.me/in-progess/made-in-athens/)

```
// custom.js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    $(".dropdown-button").dropdown();
    $(".parallax").parallax();
    $(".covervid-video").coverVid(1920, 1080);  
    $( ".masthead-arrow" ).onload("bounce", "slow");
    $("header").scroll(function() {
        $("#dropdown1").hide();
    });
});
```

I've managed to narrow the problem down to this block code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 400) {
        $(".header").addClass("scrolling").fadeIn("slow", 200);
        $("#white-to-black").addClass("scrolling").fadeTo("slow", 800);
        $(".animated_nav").addClass("scrolling");
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass("scrolling");
        $("#white-to-black").removeClass("scrolling");
        $(".animated_nav").removeClass("scrolling").slideUp("slow", 600);
    };
});

$("#secondary-nav").stick_in_parent();
```

Comment: I see only one error _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined_

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it's when you scroll pass 400px

Comment: `$(".header").addClass("scrolling").fadeIn("slow", 200)` doesn't look right as  you can either pass `duration` and `callback` or an object as options. Try either `.fadeIn("slow")` or `.fadeIn(200)` to begin with. And, also, `.fadeTo("slow", 800)` should be `.fadeTo("slow", <a number b/w 0 and 1>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 400) {
        $(".header").addClass("scrolling").fadeIn("slow"); //or time in milliseconds
        $("#white-to-black").addClass("scrolling").fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
        $(".animated_nav").addClass("scrolling");
    } else {
        $(".header").removeClass("scrolling");
        $("#white-to-black").removeClass("scrolling");
        $(".animated_nav").removeClass("scrolling").slideUp("slow"); //time in milliseconds
    };
});
```

Read more about [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeTo](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/)